# How to modify views.py and urls.py to enable an endpoint to Django app?

Tags: python, django

In my Django app I want to modify `urls.py` in order to add an end-point `users` as `localhost:8000/users`:

```
from rest_framework import routers

# ...

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', ???)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),    
    path(r'', include(router.urls))
]
```

However I don't know how to modify `views.py` to enable an endpoint. Should I create a class inside `views.py`?

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import json

def index(request):
    #...

    response_data = {}
    response_data['prediction'] = y_pred
    response_data['probability'] = round(y_prob,2)
    response_json = json.dumps(response_data)

    return HttpResponse(response_json)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, and all you want is for a URL to return some JSON, you just have to alter your `urls.py` in the usual way.

**urls.py**

```
from [app-name] import views

urlpatterns = [
    #...,    
    path("users", views.users_endpoint, name='users_endpoint'),
    #...,
]
```

**views.py**

```
# ...
def users_endpoint(request):
    #...

    response_data = {}
    response_data['prediction'] = y_pred
    response_data['probability'] = round(y_prob,2)
    response_json = json.dumps(response_data)

    return HttpResponse(response_json)
```

So the entry in `urls.py` is saying:

> When the path is `ROOT_URL/users`, call the view `users_endpoint` from the `views.py` file in the app. `[app-name]`.

Comment: Thanks. What is `[app-name]`? I have the following structure: my_app/views.py and my_app/urls.py

Comment: @ScalaBoy In that case, if you're following the usual Django structure, your `[app-name]` should be `my_app`. So you'd say `from my_app import views`. If you're new to Django, I'd highly recommend [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial—it's the official Django one, and really helped me in getting a solid start.